# Information about the Kernel data structure

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I came around this word kernel data structures while reading.

Tried to find information about this, but could'nt.

Wondering

- What are kernel data structures?
- Its requirement, usage, access?
- Organization of kernel data structure inside the kernel

Example of kernel data structures might be file_operations or c_dev.

Suggest some materials to refer about this, if naive.

Thanks

Comment: why did u not search on google?

Comment: I asked google.No help

Comment: No materials were useful

Comment: do u know what is kernel?

Comment: first read kernel carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer these articles:

http://kernelbook.sourceforge.net/

http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=256

http://tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ds/ds.html

Few books also help you.

[Linux Kernel Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470343435)

[Understanding the Linux Kernel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005652)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Ya I read about Linux kernel Architecture, and understood the basics.